# strapi - change upload folder location and restrict access to files

Tags: strapi

Is there a way in strapi to configure location for uploading media and also restrict access to it?

[the docs for configuring the middleware](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins/upload.html#configuration) lists only one option for changing maxFileSize.

Strapi uses is [koa-body](https://github.com/dlau/koa-body) and formidable to process files but I couldnt find option to configure path there also.

I'm on strapi v3.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

Restricting access to files: As far as I know, the upload plugin does not support restricting access to files, based on user-permissions authentication. For example, the aws bucket provider expects a public bucket and the local upload provider serves all files indiscriminately. Options for getting around this include:

1. Making a custom upload provider
2. Modifying the upload plugin, develop a custom plugin
3. Fully custom uploads in a strapi model service
4. ....

Upload folder location: Strapi-provider-upload-local picks up a path from the middleware config [here](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/0ab3503e3c68c0e794878324a866ce9e6cfe5d47/packages/strapi-provider-upload-local/lib/index.js#L20). Although I don't know if this variable is used anywhere else and can be (safely) changed in the middleware config file.

Comment: I really wanted to inject that config value like you thought might not be the end of the world... but upon closer inspection, `/uploads` is hard-coded all over the place.

Comment: @digitalextremist did you ever found a fix for this, I am looking to move the upload path outside the project directory so that whenever my app redeploys I don't lose all uploaded files